Assigning an expression to variables in C language
I have an assignment in C where i have to create a small program that would calculate some things. The only thing im struggling with is that according to said assignment, i need to let user declare x as 1.825*10^2 using scanf function. However, when doing that my program just exits.
Here's the relevant part of my code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// VARIANT 2

int main()
{   
  
    float x, y, z, ans1, ans2, answer;
    printf("Declare x:\n");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("Declare y:\n");
    scanf("%f", &y);
    printf("Declare z:\n");
    scanf("%f", &z);

    printf("%f %f %f \n", x,y,z);
}

Im declaring X in terminal as 1.825*pow(10,2). My guess is that scanf doesnt allow/read expressions - but the assignment is clear that i need to declare X via scanf.

Read scientific notation scanf

Would it help if you declared the base and exponent as ints, like float x; int y, z; and then if (scanf("%f*%d^%d", &x, &y, &z) == 3) { /* success */ } ?

You're confused — or the question is confused — about "declaring variables" using the scanf() function.  You declare variables independently of functions like scanf().  You can read the variables using functions like scanf().  If the user is supposed to enter 1.825*10^2, you are going to have to do a lot of work.  You could enter 182.5, or 1.825E2 or 1.825e+2 or a number of other notations, but inputting 1.825*10^2 is definitely either cruel and unusual punishment or a misinterpretation of what's required.  I hope it's a misinterpretation for your sake.

Show the exact text of the portion of the assignment that says what input text must be processed.

First, what you're describing is not "declaring" x.  You're describing reading in a value for x.
The %f format specifier for scanf expects a decimal floating point constant to be read, and the string 1.825*pow(10,2) is not such a constant.
The way you would specify such a value would be 1.825e2.

Oh, i get it now. Thank you!


scanf does not evaluate any expressions. It only reads the (in your case float) constant

If you want to evaluate expressions entered as strings you need to use 3rd party libraries - for example tinuExpr


example:
https://godbolt.org/z/v1EM4deYh
int main(void)
{
    char str[100];
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    printf("Result: %f\n", te_interp(str, 0));
}

when you enter sqrt(5^2+7^2+11^2+(8-2)^2) the result will be 15.198684
Your expression: https://godbolt.org/z/4PPvfT5sd

I want to elaborate more on previous comments and answers by going on a more basic level:
What you enter in console it's always at the low level a string of characters. It's the job of the program to interpret the input as needed. Converting from a string of characters to the object it represents (e.g. a number) is called parsing. scanf does just that. It reads and then it interprets the input as requested (e.g. %s for string, %d for integer, %f for floating point number and so on). It does the parsing for you.
scanf and family have very specific formats they recognize. You can say 1.825*10^2 is a number in scientific notation mathematically, but it's not a valid format for scanf. scanf does accept numbers in scientific notation, but they need to be in this scientific format: 1.825e2.
If you are ok with changing the input to 1.825e2 then you are done.
However if you want to accept this 1.825*10^2 then you need to manually parse the input or use a library that does that.
I hope I've made things a bit more clear.
